# How to set "Resolution Unit" when regenerating\saving an image

Tags: c#, image, tiff

I'm trying to investigate an issue I thinking I'm seeing in an application that generates a TIF image.

To do this I'm trying to regenerating\saving the image myself following this [msdn Encoder.Compression example](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.imaging.encoder.compression.aspx) (except I'm using CompressionCCITT4).

The output file has a 'Resolution unit' = 2 but I would like to set that to 1.

Questions:

Any ideas how to do set the 'Resolution unit'?

Any ideas on the effect that would\should have on the image?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Disclaimer: Being a Java guy, I don't know how to set it using the library you describe. So I'll only answer question part 2:

> Any ideas on the effect that would\should have on the image?

**The quick answer is: None.** It only matters when you import the image into a page-setting/layout program, word processor, print it, etc. But a lot of software simply assumes 72dpi in both x/y dimensions regardless.

Here's what the TIFF spec says:

> Typically, TIFF pixel- editors do not care about the resolution, but applications (such as page layout programs) do care.

And:

> 1 = No absolute unit of measurement. Used for images that may have a non-square aspect ratio, but no meaningful absolute dimensions.
>
> The drawback of ResolutionUnit=1 is that different applications will import the image
> at different sizes. Even if the decision is arbitrary, it might be better to use dots per
> inch or dots per centimeter, and to pick XResolution and YResolution so that the aspect ratio is correct and the maximum dimension of the image is about four inches (the “four” is arbitrary.)